# Java plugin doesn't appear in Firefox after Java 8 installation

Tags: java, servlets, java-8

After Java 8 release I have deleted Java 7 and installed Java 8 SDK and JRE. I checked installation on http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp but according to the this web-site I don't have Java*

Also I found that Java plugin desappear from Firefox, thus servlets don't work.

Does enybody know if it's a correct beheveral of Java 8 because it's just a intermediate version of Java? Or it should work and it means that something wrong with my enviroment?

- I checked it manually: Hello Words apps compile and run in Eclipse. Also System.getProperty("java.specification.version") returns 1.8.0_20-ea

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 is definately not an intermediate version of Java 8. So it should work.

Your `System.getProperty` indicates that you are running an early access build though.

I tested it on my machine, where I downloaded the official release one day after launch from the official Oracle site, and `System.getProperty("java.specification.version")` prints `1.8`.